# Cannot publish a Power BI report from a Power BI optimized Client to Power BI Report Server

Tags: powerbi

I recently installed a fresh-out-of-the-box Power BI server on a windows server.
I had it configured and everything works just fine, I also have a web portal and a web service up and running.

I also installed a Power BI Client optimized for Power BI Server because I know the standard Power BI Desktop will cause some problems with Power BI Report Server.

For some reason, whenever I try to publish using the PBI Desktop, or when I save a report to a *.pibx file and try to import it through the web portal, it encounters an unknown error and also tells me the file might be corrupted.

Is there any known error I can look up, or rather are there log files I can view which will tell me the exact error so I'll know what to fix?